# Will the windows boot loader replace Grub2 if i install windows now

Tags: grub2, windows, bootloader

Well, I've got a new lappy. Its preinstalled with Ubuntu and windows 8.1. I want to triple boot it Windows 10. So I've heard that if one installs Windows later, it ignores grub... Is it true?
I still want to boot windows 10 with grub2

Comment: It tends to ignore Ubuntu altogether, so be careful...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this will cause issues, but usually it's nothing that's too hard to repair.

When you install Windows, it will overwrite GRUB, and make it so you can only boot to Windows. Luckily, `boot-repair` (available from community.ubuntu.com) usually reinstates GRUB as the default bootloader.

Sometimes GRUB won't have an entry for Windows. If this happens, boot Ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub`.